# How to run .Net Win-Forms application on a 64 Bit OS?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made a .Net win-forms application in C#, on a 32 bit OS (Windows 7).
It doesn't work on the deployed client-terminal/machine which has a 64 bit OS (Server 2008).

What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: try to run them window mode 32 by change their setting i thing it will work !

Comment: Can you expand on "It doesn't work..."?

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'?

Comment: *Doesn't work* is a term commonly employed by people who don't care/understand how computers work and totally inappropriate to a software developer. So start by explaining what doesn't work. What are the symptoms, because your scenario is pretty common and it should work. Also what is the reason for running WinForms application (which is a client application) on a server OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the *Build* tab of the project's properties and make sure the platform target is set to **x86**. (This is just my first guess based on the vague information provided. The problem might be caused by something completely else, e.g. the terminal server environment as such.)

You should only change this setting if you need your application to address a large amount of memory or you  definitely want to make sure it runs as a 64-bit process.

The AnyCPU setting can hardly be recommended as it may cause you all sorts of pain with respect to native dependencies (I'm not saying it should never be used, but it should be very well considered whether the additional overhead required for deployment and testing is worth the trouble).

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly. But couldn't really get a RCA.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have used some feature that is not available while running the app in x64. Change the build configuration to x86.

If it does work now, you have used some libraries (COM, ActiveX, Office 2007, WinAPI, ...) that does not like to be called from 64 bit.

If it works now, ask yourself: why do I want my app to run using x64 bit? What do I gain? Does it really need to use that much memory?

There is no problem with running a x86 bit app on a x64 bit platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActiveX controls inside your application or anything else that is not portable to x64, you might have to change the build target to "x86".

Answer (score 0):

If it's a genuine x86 application your x64 environment shouldn't have any problem running it. So make sure all your libraries and your own binary are x86 compatible and don't use x86 exclusive features like specific COM libraries.

Answer (score -1):

You should ensure that you project is being built with the "Any CPU" platform.

The default is sometimes to build for "x86".

Comment: No, AnyCPU is the most frequent cause that applications don't run on a 64-bit OS. It's also the reason that the default for new projects has been changed to x86 in VS 2010.

Comment: That of course only works if all his components and such are also built for Any CPU. If any of the components are compiled for 32-bit, then this might very well be the cause of his problems.

Answer (score -1):

Check your build config. I think VS will default to building the app for x86 platforms if you develop in a 32-bit environment. Either change to x64 or AnyCPU, rebuild and try again.

.stompp

Comment: Hmm, I realise I was a bit triggerhappy answering this one. Please disregard my answer.